# Why another echo is needed in custom github action output

Tags: bash, github-actions

From the documentation of github actions:

```
outputs:
random-number:
  description: "Random number"
  value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-id }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: random-number-generator
    run: echo "::set-output name=random-id::$(echo $RANDOM)"
    shell: bash
```

In the run clause 2 echos exist, one for the whole line and one echo $RANDOM

Isn't the second echo unnessecary?

On my computer

```
echo "::set-output name=random-id::$(echo $RANDOM)"
```

outputs:

> ::set-output name=random-id::28124

while

```
echo "::set-output name=random-id::$RANDOM"
```

outputs

> ::set-output name=random-id::28123

so both works.

So why is $(echo $RANDOM) needed ?

Comment: who says it's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from [Metadata syntax / outputs for composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-composite-actions) and is not strictly needed.

The documentation mentions:

> If you need to pass environment variables into an action, make sure your action runs a command shell to perform variable substitution.

By using `$(echo $RANDOM)`, you "force" said variable substitution.